# Display and hide content using checkbox in Options Framework Theme

Tags: theme-options

I am currently using [Options Framework Theme](http://wptheming.com) for making WordPress options panel. I created a checkbox in admin panel by this code in `options.php`

```
$options[] = array(
'name' => __('Input Checkbox Name', 'options_framework_theme'),
'desc' => __('Check to display.'),
'id' => 'example_checkbox_2',
'std' => 'true',
'type' => 'checkbox');
```

I want to display different content when the checkbox is checked or unchecked. So, I inserted this code in file template (`footer.php`)

```
<?php if ( of_get_option('example_checkbox2') != 'true') { ?>
        <p>checked</p>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <p>unchecked</p>
<?php } ?>
```

My problem is:

When I checked or uncheck the checkbox, "`checked`" is displayed in my footer.

Could anybody help how to retrieve and display content from checkbox correctly?

Any respond are highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

'true' should be '1':

```
$options[] = array(
    'name' => __('Input Checkbox Name', 'options_framework_theme'),
    'desc' => __('Check to display.'),
    'id' => 'example_checkbox_2',
    'std' => '1',
    'type' => 'checkbox'
);
```

and:

```
<?php if ( 1 == of_get_option('example_checkbox2') ) { ?>
        <p>checked</p>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <p>unchecked</p>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your respond.

It works very well. I made a miss-type before. I should type of_get_option('example_checkbox_2') instead of of_get_option('example_checkbox2')

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it, except use it like this on your template.

`<?php if ( of_get_option('display_second_section_category') == '1' ) { ?>`

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?